# NestedList in sencha touch and Back Button

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a nested list in Sencha Touch app.

[Similar to this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/nestedlist)

When the app load and I click CAR I move to a nested list.
Clicking BACK, bring to the CAR list again.

I would need add another BACK BUTTON alike on the page wich will bring me to the CAR list.

Could you provide me a sample of code or do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking at [source code](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/source/NestedList.html#Ext-dataview-NestedList) to see how `onBackTap` works and if you can do the same?